# bash No such file or directory error thrown

Tags: bash, shell

```
 cat some.properties
/server/pdu/secure/enabled=true
/pdu/secure/servers=aninath-lnx:49188
/pdu/unsecure/servers=
/secure/truststore/password=635db14e5350e23142c5c65e3caa50d7
/ui/http/port=8100
/ui/https/port=8443
```

While Executing the following command

```
 **. some.properties**
-bash: /server/pdu/secure/enabled=true: No such file or directory
-bash: /pdu/secure/servers=aninath-lnx:49188: No such file or directory
-bash: /pdu/unsecure/servers=: No such file or directory
-bash: /secure/truststore/password=635db14e5350e23142c5c65e3caa50d7: No such file or directory
-bash: /ui/http/port=8100: No such file or directory
-bash: /ui/https/port=8443: No such file or directory
```

I was trying to get the propertyvalue from the propertyName for that i have used
. some.properties
source some.properties
and I got these error's

Comment: Yes so ? Can you be a bit more precise ? What were you expecting ? Have you use cat before ?

Answer (score 0):

Only letters, numbers and underscores are valid characters to form Bash identifiers, you can't use slashes.

Comment: Then How can i get the propertyValue based on the PropertyName.

Comment: @anish you are using slashes to define your variables, they are not valid characters for identifiers, instead bash parse it as a command and tries to find a file with that name and execute it.